# Phonegap - Eclipse - opening files or external websites

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Good morning, first of all sorry if this have been asked before, i've found no answer yet and i've been looking for it for a long time.

The problem: there's links to external websites in my app. This links always open inside my app. I want them to open like the following image, asking me what app i want to use to open the link:

Click to see image
http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/complete-action-i.jpg

Another problem is that i have some files i want to download from the app. They have the same problem. I would like the requested file to download automatically but it does nothing.

Wish you could help me, i am new in this and i'm a little (or too much) lost. Appreciate your help¡¡¡ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can do this with the InAppBrowser plugin: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open

If you set the `target=_system`, it will "Opens in the system's web browser." I think if you have set a default web browser already on your device, it will probably use that web browser and not give you the prompt in your screen shot. I don't think there is a way to force the system to ask you which app to use, unless the user somehow clears that association/setting.